# How to model breakage events for electronic devices using a Weibull distribution?

Tags: modeling, curve-fitting, hazard, weibull-distribution

I got age data (in years) of gas heatings from a random sample of about N=700 participants.
So participants were asked how old their gas heating is in years.

Now I like to model that age distribution (curve fitting) as well as the breakage rate within a given timeframe (e.g. within 1 year - so how many heatings may break within 12 months).

So far I have fitted my age data to a Weibull distribution. Besides the shape of the data: is this distritution edaquate for age data? So I am a bit confused because I read that using Weibull is an approach for modeling failure data as it can take into account increasing failure rate over time. But in my case we are talking about increasing failure rate as older the heating becomes - how to I model there two different scenarios?

But my problem is that I have no clue how to model the expected breakage rate based on the age data. Is this even possible? Of course, if I had yearly breakage rates, I could fit those data directly - but I only have the age data.

Is there any approach for this?

PS: So how can I model the hazard rate based on the age distribution? And as a hazard rate gives me the failure possibility for a given age - how can I retrieve the expected failures within a given timeframe?